# Pandas - formatting tick labels

Tags: python, plot, pandas, axes

I have a pandas dataframe with dates in column 0 and times in column 1. I wish to plot data in columns 2,3,4...n as a function of the date and time. How do I go about formatting the tick labels in the code below so that I can display both the Date and time in the plot. Thanks in advance. I'm new to stackoverflow (and python for that matter) so sorry but I don't have enough a reputation that allows me to attach the image that I get from my code below.

```
 df3=pd.read_table('filename.txt',
                       sep=',',
                       skiprows=4,
                       na_values='N\A',
                       index_col=[0,1]) # date and time are my indices    

datedf=df3.ix[['01:07:2013'],['AOT_1640','AOT_870']] 

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
    for i, c in enumerate(datedf.columns):
        print i,c
        datedf[c].plot(ax=axes[i], figsize=(12, 10), title=c)
    plt.savefig('testing123.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: You can always add link to image.

Comment: Or you can post the content of `filename.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You could combine columns 0 and 1 into a single date & time column, set that to your index and then the pandas .plot attribute will automatically use the index as the x-tick labels. Hard to say how it will work with your data set as I can't see it but the main point is that Pandas uses the index for the x-tick labels unless you tell it not to. Be warned that this doesn't work well with hierarchical indexing (at least in my very limited experience).